# EJS Front-End unable to find the image I'm trying to display

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs, venom

[I have these two methods inside a VenomBot class, that generates a QR Code image and stores it in a folder called images.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dbFA.png)

[This is the organization of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNA8U.png)

[And these are the functions that starts the process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxhfB.png)

[Finally, that's the front-end EJS code that was supposed to show the QR Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YD8aI.png)

The problem is that everything is going fine, but when the QR Code was about to get loaded at the front-end, it appears that the EJS file isn't finding it, why?

I've already tried to change the image path in every way possible

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Is it static middleware enabled , like this , app.use(express.static('/images'))

Comment: Yes, it is! I'm already using it